# Custom pings on announce command Discord.js

Tags: discord.js

Right now I have an announce command that pings everyone when I send an announcement, but I want to change the ping so that it pings a certain role in my server. The first code is the code that works and pings everyone, and the second two lines of code are the custom ping that is not sending as a ping but just a line of text. How can I make the second two lines of code send as a ping like the @everyone?

```
message.channel.send(`@everyone`)
message.channel.send(announceEmbed);
```

```
message.channel.send(`@Stream`)
message.channel.send(announceEmbed);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an exception that only `everyone` role would ping the `everyone` role of the guild when sent as `@everyone`. But it is not the case for other roles, as well as for member and channel. So
You can ping/mention the particular role using the ID of the role,

```
message.channel.send(`<@&roleid>`);
```

Comment: Lets say my role id was 11111, would the code be `message.channel.send('@11111')` or would it contain all of the symbols that you have in the code, like `message.channel.send('<@&11111>')`

Comment: Yes, it would contain the symbols like I have given and like I said, only everyone role will be mentioned when just sent as `@everyone` but not the case for others. Also you need to use the Template Literals (${}) in backticks(\`) to send the value of the thing inside ${}. Eg: `message.channel.send(\`<@&${roleid}>\`);` to send the value of roleid in that place. If you do like what I did, then you it will send <@&roleid> as a message to the channel itself because the whole is considered as string. What I've sent as answer is wrong. So use Template Literals.